# How to send a file from Quarkus to a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resteasy, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm writing a Quarkus microservice that is meant to communicate with a main Spring Boot application.

In order to make calls to the Spring Boot app, I wrote a REST client based on this [Quarkus tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client) and it's working fine for some endpoints.
The problem happens when I try to upload a file from Quarkus to Spring boot, I cannot get it to work properly. I followed [this other tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-multipart) to work with multipart requests.

Here's my multipart object on my Quarkus application:

```
public class MultipartBody {
    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public InputStream file;

    @FormParam("fileName")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String fileName;
}
```

Here's the endpoint on REST client in Quarkus:

```
@POST
@Path("/file")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
ProjectFile upload(@HeaderParam(AUTH_HEADER) String apiToken, @MultipartForm MultipartBody data);
```

Here's how I build the MultipartBody object:

```
    InputStream stream = IOUtils.toInputStream(contentString, Charset.defaultCharset());
    MultipartBody data = MultipartBody.builder()
            .file(stream)
            .fileName(filename)
            .build();
```

The endpoint in Spring Boot application:

```
@PostMapping("/file")
public ProjectFile receive(@RequestParam MultipartFile inputFile)
```

It throws an error saying that `inputFile` is not provided:

```
Required request part 'inputFile' is not present - org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException - Required request part 'inputFile' is not present
```

If I change the `@RequestParam` for `@RequestBody`, then the `inputFile` parameter is always `null`. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you able to use other clients to send a file? Unclear where the problem is, but try to isolate it

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tested the endpoint using Postman and I'm able to upload a text file successfully. On Postman I select `Body -> form-data` with KEY=`inputFile` and VALUE is a text file in my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to use `MultipartFormDataOutput` class, multipart form data field is missing **file name**. In your case, trying to use `@PartFilename` annotation.

> Must be used in conjunction with @MultipartForm. This defines the filename for a part

```
try (InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(currentFile)) {

  MultipartFormDataOutput multipartFormDataOutput = new MultipartFormDataOutput();

  multipartFormDataOutput.addFormData("file", fileInputStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE, currentFile.getName());
  
  multipartFormDataOutput.addFormData("metaData",objectMapper.writeValueAsString(fileMeta),MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

  // Call client to upload file

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Quarkus moving to rest-client reactive the correct usage will be to use the class `QuarkusMultipartForm`.

Lets take the below example but with multiple files and a String payload as well expected by Spring Controller endpoint.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/multipart",
      consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Map<String, String> multipart(@RequestParam String jsonPayload,
      @RequestPart MultipartFile[] files) {
    return Map.of("fileName", String.join(": ", "File received is : ", files[0].getName()));
  }
```

Quarkus application to call the endpoint will look like
based on rest easy reactive we can receive the data via custom call or MultipartFormDataInput.

```
public class MultiPartPayloadFormData {

  @RestForm("files")
  @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  List<FileUpload> files;

  @RestForm("jsonPayload")
  @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  String jsonPayload;
}
```

Service call to spring endpoint is via

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "spring-multipart")
@RegisterClientHeaders
@Path("/api")
public interface MultipartSpringService {

  @POST
  @Path("/multipart")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  Map<String, String> springMultipartCall(QuarkusMultipartForm dataParts);

  @POST
  @Path("/test")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  Map<String, String> testCallSpring(@RestForm("payload") String payload);
}
```

Now we need to build the `QuarkusMultipartForm` object.

```
  @POST
  @Path("/multipart")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  public Map<String, String> multipart(MultiPartPayloadFormData data) {

    QuarkusMultipartForm qmf = new QuarkusMultipartForm();
    qmf.attribute("jsonPayload", data.getJsonPayload(), "jsonPayload");
    data.getFiles().forEach(f -> {
      qmf.binaryFileUpload("file", f.name(), f.filePath().toString(), f.contentType());
    });

    return springService.springMultipartCall(qmf);
  }
```

For the specific answer to the actual question

```
@PostMapping("/file")
public ProjectFile receive(@RequestParam MultipartFile inputFile)
```

The solution will be

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "spring-multipart")
@RegisterClientHeaders
public interface MultipartSpringService {

  @POST
  @Path("/file")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  Map<String, String> springReceiveCall(QuarkusMultipartForm dataParts);
```

And the call to the method will be like below

```
    QuarkusMultipartForm qmf = new QuarkusMultipartForm();
    qmf.binaryFileUpload("inputFile", f.name(), f.filePath().toString(), f.contentType());
    });
    return springService.springReceiveCall(qmf);
```